# TryExecuteTask task not coming out of Running state

Tags: c#, .net

I have implemented a simple scheduler and in that i am executing the task one by one. This is important as the order of execution cannot be out of order.
Now i am having List and i am using one thread to loop though the tasks and execute them one by one

But after few time/hour the execution get stuck on the below line

```
  TryExecuteTask(_tasks[0]);
```

When i check that task Status it was in Running and never coming out of that status. And i think that blocks the other task also

So i am thinking that is there anyway to apply some timeout here. So say, if task is not completed within 30 seconds then it get auto killed.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Have you noticed how questions with code are better than those loosely describing code?

Comment: List<> is not thread safe, in your case it would be good to use BlockingCollection . Add code for more info

Comment: Deadlock is common when you use threads, especially when you don't lock when you need to.  Use the Debug + Windows + Threads to see what those threads are doing.